# Flutter Execution Failed for task app:externalNativeBuildDebug Exception | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

My Project is worked well in the previous version of flutter but after the update of flutter my project is not running and getting Build failed exception. The error in the console is this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /home/murali/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/murali/myproject/android/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a --target api_util}
  [1/2] Building CXX object 'CMakeFiles/api_util.dir/home/murali/myproject/ios/Classes/api_util.cpp.o'
  FAILED: /home/murali/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi21 --gcc-toolchain=/home/murali/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/murali/Android/Sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot  -Dapi_util_EXPORTS  -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT 'CMakeFiles/api_util.dir/home/murali/myproject/ios/Classes/api_util.cpp.o' -MF CMakeFiles/api_util.dir/home/murali/myproject/ios/Classes/api_util.cpp.o.d -o 'CMakeFiles/api_util.dir/home/murali/myproject/ios/Classes/api_util.cpp.o' -c "/home/murali/myproject/ios/Classes/api_util.cpp"
  /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue by adding Android NDK `20.1.5948944` in SDK Manger and untick all other NDKs